# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS language pack installed, BUT inserting specific letters does not work

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, special-characters

As you can see in the below image the additional language pack is installed. The switch works, but inserting the Romanian specific letters from the keyboard does not work.

I am using the same version of Ubuntu on 2 different laptops, on one laptop inserting from keyboard specific letters using the keys: [, ], ;, ', \ inserts my language specific letters: ă, â, î, ș, ț when the keyboard layout is switched to RO. On the other laptop only the language layout switch works, inserting RO specific letters does not work, only inserting [, ], ;, ', , whether the layout is switched to EN or RO.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**@Solved**

Must be installed / selected the languagepack "Romanian (standard)", not "Romanian".

It's non-intuitive the language search box when you want to install the language pack. If you type in the language search box only "Romanian" it displays "Romanian", and then after selection it displays the first 2 as Moldavian and Romanian, and then 3 more versions of "Romanian", the 4th being Romanian (standard).

How does a user know the difference between "Romanian" and "Romanian (standard)"? Why only "Standard" has "special characters"? Standard means "standard" in any language, it does not mean "special" (special characters).

Comment: You can see the comments on the different Romanian variants in the [source file](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/blob/master/symbols/ro). If you think it should be changed, you may want to submit an issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues